# Can late-binding in C++ be done without the need for heap-memory when using composition?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, composition, dynamic-dispatch, run-time-polymorphism

late-binding or runtime-polymorphism needs 2 things: a base pointer and a virtual method.

```
class FrameWorkClassBase {
  public:
    virtual void method() = 0;
};

class FrameWorkClassDerived: public FrameWorkClassBase {
public:
    virtual void method() override { ... }
}

class ProductionConsumerClass { // uses composition
  public:
    void method() {
        this->m_sptr->method(); // dynamic dispatch
    }
  
  private:
    // ptr to base class, composition at work
    std::shared_ptr<FrameWorkClassBase> m_sptr =
                              std::make_shared<FrameWorkClassDerived>();
}
```

there seems to be a bias towards using heap memory for polymorphic object creation rather than stack allocated objects, especially when it comes to using "polymorphic object" as component objects. Is this a requirement: is it the nature of the C++ language as a whole that forces the use of heap memory for "polymorphic component objects" ? Are there any design patterns that overcome the need for using heap memory for "polymorphic component objects" ?

Note: I do not want to use base class l-value reference(`FrameWorkClassBase&`) as a data member in `ProductionConsumerClass` as i do not have life-time-guarantee/ownership of the referred object.

Comment: References exhibit late binding behavior without heap allocation

Comment: I have written entire C++ applications with plenty of late binding and zero heap usage.

Comment: Read also books on garbage collection (e.g. the [GC handbook](https://gchandbook.org/)....)

Comment: Why do you need `m_sptr` to be a pointer to `FrameWorkClassBase`? And a pointer in the first place? Why not `FrameWorkClassDerived m_frameworkObject;`?

Comment: because you loose "type substitution", you have essentially tied yourself to an implementation value type rather than a generic base type that would allow you to swap an implementation(derived class) for another implementation. your code is becomes tightly coupled with an implementation.

Comment: FIrst, if you answer to someone in particular, please use `@username` otherwise we don't get a notification. Second, you have tied yourself to an implementation anyway by having `= std::make_shared<FrameWorkClassDerived>();` right there in the class declaration. Now if you have `m_sptr = findSomeFrameworkObject();` where `findSomeFrameworkObject()` returns a pointer to `FrameWorkClassBase`, then you decouple yourself from the implementation. But then you have a lifetime and ownership issue that is completely orthogonal to late bindings. Who owns that framework object?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. extacly my point , in C++ when it comes to late binding it has orthogonal stuff. I have explicitly called out that I do not want to use references, for this exact situation. Is it the nature of C++ to be in this situation ?

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "this situation". You have a framework object.  What is its lifetime? What other object owns it? Does the answer depend on whether the framework object is polymorphic?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. the framework object is polymorphic. "this situation" refers to the fact that you have be in a conundrum between having to select a pointer to a heap allocated object were ownership is shared vs having to use l/r-value references where ownership is not very explicitly conveyed  other than to have the lifetime of the polymorphic component object extended. You are on the fence to decide between "heap allocated polymorphic objects" with a shared_ptr which has explicit shared ownership and lifetime guarantees vs l/r value references that do not have ownership guarantee.

Comment: You have an ownership problem, the fact that the framework object is polymorphic is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use heap allocation for late binding to work:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
  virtual void print() { std::cout << "Base\n"; }
};

struct Derived : public Base {
  void print() override { std::cout << "Derived\n"; }
};

struct Composed {
  Base b;
  Derived d;
};

int main() {
  Base b;
  Derived d;
  Composed c;

  Base &bb{b}, &bd{d}, &cbb{c.b}, &cbd{c.d};

  bb.print();   // Base
  bd.print();   // Derived
  cbb.print();  // Base
  cbd.print();  // Derived
}
```

In the example above, no heap allocation takes place and all reference variables are of type `Base&`. Late binding works just fine.